# Duplicating Sheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to construct a spreadsheet to track project data, with a worksheet for each project and an overview sheet that provides summary information.  I constructed a sheet based on a sample set of projects, and it all seems to work the way I expected.  Adding a new project takes a lot of care and feeding, though, so I decided to give the user a button to click, a dialog to ask for a project name, and let the script do the rest.

I created a template sheet (conveniently titled "Template"), and I've attempted to script duplication of that sheet to the end of the workbook using the `Worksheets("Name").Copy` method as suggested on MSDN.  This attempt is reflected in the first few lines of code below.  After that I take a template row and add it to the end of the list on the overview sheet (named "Dashboard").

What ends up happening (as far as I can tell) is that the sheet doesn't copy, the last sheet in the workbook gets selected, and `ActiveSheet.Name = Name` ends up renaming it, blowing up my dashboard sheet that uses `INDIRECT` to find and represent data.

Here's the code I currently have (inefficient as it is):

```
Sub AddSOW()
    ' Duplicate the template sheet
    Dim Name As String
    Name = InputBox("SOW Name")
    Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Name


    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ' Find the last row of data
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ' Decide if to copy based on column A
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
        If ThisValue = "Template" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 50).Copy
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Value = Name
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

No errors get thrown, it just doesn't work.  Stepping through doesn't help either.

Comment: First, `Name` is probably a protected word, so rename your variable to something like `SName`.  Second, since you copy the Template Sheet to the end, try replacing `ActiveSheet.Name = SName` with `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SName`

Comment: Using `Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SName` throws an error: `Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was causing my own problem.

In order to ensure that the user doesn't modify the template worksheet, I had it hidden.  Duplicating it was also duplicating the `.Visible` property setting, so the sheets were actually getting duplicated, but since they weren't visible, the last sheet in the book that was visible was getting selected, and therefore the one getting renamed.

I updated the code with some error checking so canceling the input box doesn't cause problems.  Here's the working code.

```
Sub AddSOW()
    Dim SName As String

    SName = InputBox("SOW Name")
    ' Duplicate the template sheet
    If SName <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Template").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = SName
        Worksheets("Template").Visible = False
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select
        ' Find the last row of data
        FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through each row
        For x = 2 To FinalRow
            ' Decide if to copy based on column A
            ThisValue = Cells(x, 1).Value
            If ThisValue = "Template" Then
                Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 50).Copy
                NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                ActiveCell.Value = SName
            End If
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```